APEX ORA-01403: no data found when click on pencil (edit rows) in interactive report
I'm developing an APEX application on already existing table defined as follow:
CREATE TABLE "RUN_GROUP"
(   "COD_RUN" CHAR(10 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PROVIDER" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
"DESTINATION" CHAR(100 CHAR),
"OWNER" CHAR(2 CHAR)
 ) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_RUN_GROUP" ON "RUN_GROUP" ("COD_RUN")
;
ALTER TABLE "RUN_GROUP" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_RUN_GROUP" PRIMARY KEY ("COD_RUN")
USING INDEX "PK_RUN_GROUP"  ENABLE;

I generate an interactive report on this table and, when I click on pencil for editing a row I recived the  error:
*ORA-01403: no data found
I tried defining a similar table but adding an ID:
CREATE TABLE "RUN_GROUP_2"
(   
"ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE NOT NULL ENABLE,     
"COD_RUN" CHAR(10 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PROVIDER" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
"DESTINATION" CHAR(100 CHAR),
"OWNER" CHAR(2 CHAR)
) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_RUN_GROUP_2" ON "RUN_GROUP_2" ("ID")

Then I generate the interactive report on this table and the pencil works fine.
It's IDENTITY column mandatory or there is a way to have the pencil work without it ?
Thanks
